# Retrieve data from Firebase Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 screens within my app. The 1st screen passes an argument to the 2nd screen. In this 2nd screen, I need to make use of the argument received from the 1st screen and initialize an `list` object within the `initState` method.

The issue I'm facing is, until the `build` method doesn't gets executed, I wouldn't be able to access the argument that was passed from the 1st screen, therefore unable to initialize the `list` object.

Is there a way I can access the argument passed from the 1st screen and initialize the `list` when the initState method is invoked?

Thank you so much for your time in advance.

SCREEN 1:

```
.
.
.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          ContentPage.routeName,
          arguments: topicID,
        );
      },
}
```

SCREEN 2:

```
List<String> topicID;
List<String> response;
.
.
.
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    topicID = response;
}
.
.
.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    response = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
}
.
.
.
```

Getting the below error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Projects/Mobile/newapp/lib/main.dart:39:14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Please provide some code you already tried.

Comment: Hi @Akif I have added the code to the problem. Thanks!